# Python SMTP Library Blank Email with time

Tags: python, email, smtp

I'm using the built in Python library to send email. Everything works, except when I put a time in the message that I'm sending. 
like `7:30 pm`.

When I put a time in the email message, the email recipient just gets a blank email.  If I remove the time, the email sends just fine. I'm guessing that something with the time screws up the email. What should I change in my code, so I can put a time in the email body. Thanks!

```
from smtplib import SMTP
def sendEmail(message,address):
    debuglevel = 0

    smtp = SMTP()
    smtp.set_debuglevel(debuglevel)
    #connect to the email server
    smtp.connect('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login('ouremail@gmail.com', 'ourpassword')
    #set the email to be sent from
    from_addr = "Auto Notification <sender email>"
    #send the email from our address and the message and recepients provided in the function definition.
    smtp.sendmail(from_addr, address, message)
    smtp.quit()

finalStr = "The  Girls Varsity Basketball  has been changed to 02/06/2018 at 7:30 pm * - ( previously 6:15 pm  ) at Clear Lake High School"

sendEmail(finalStr, 'myemail@gmail.com')
```

Comment: Have you looked at the raw source of the email? Is that blank, too? I can't think of any reason why the email wold be blank just because of a time.

Comment: The only difference is that it is a line lower, but  otherwise it looks the same. @Barmar

Comment: It's a line lower in the good email or the bad email? There's supposed to be a blank line between the header and the body of the message, is that missing in the blank one?

Comment: It's missing on the bad one. How do I get it to move down a line? @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the characters are being misinterpreted as control characters during transmission to the SMTP server. Try encoding the string as MIMEText:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

#send the email from our address and the message and recepients provided in the function definition.
encoded_message = MIMEText(message).as_string()
smtp.sendmail(from_addr, address, encoded_message)
```

Here's how the result differs when transmitted. Notice that the encoding is declared in the working example.

**Before**

```
send: b'The  Girls Varsity Basketball  has been changed to 02/06/2018 at 7:30 pm * - ( previously 6:15 pm  ) at Clear Lake High School\r\n.\r\n'
```

**After**:

```
send: b'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\nThe  Girls Varsity Basketball  has been changed to 02/06/2018 at 7:30 pm * - ( previously 6:15 pm  ) at Clear Lake High School\r\n.\r\n'
```